# Remux contents of multiple files to .mkv using batch

Tags: windows, video, batch-file, cmd, mkv

I have a number of video files from TV shows and I want to add subtitles subtitles to each of them. While I can use MKV merge for a few files, but here the number of files is  too much, and doing each one individually would take a lot of time.
I used the following:

```
     for %x in (*.mp4) do mkvmerge "%x" -o "%~nx.mkv"
```

But it will only mux mp4 to mkv, and not add the subtitles(srt). My video files and subtitles have the same name for each episode. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
 for %x in (*.mp4) do mkvmerge -o "%~nx.mkv" "%~x" "%~nx.srt"
```

For more info look at the [docu](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html).

Comment: I love you in a totally non-sexual way!

Comment: is there a way to add subtitle delay in ms from the subtitle filename?

Comment: Yes, you can grab the delay from the file name and add it to the command line, look at the `--sync` option https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html